# this android activity is not working

Tags: android

this code is not working since i have added showPopup() method, i couldn't figure out the reason. whats the problem in this code?

```
package com.example.healthcity.activities;

import org.taptwo.android.widget.CircleFlowIndicator;
import org.taptwo.android.widget.ViewFlow;

import com.example.healthcity.R;
import com.example.healthcity.dataobjs.DemoDataAdapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;

public class DemoViewFlowActivity extends Activity {

    private ViewFlow viewFlow;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bf_home_screen);
        // viewFlow = (ViewFlow) findViewById(R.id.viewflow);
        // viewFlow.setAdapter(new DemoDataAdapter(this));
        // CircleFlowIndicator indic = (CircleFlowIndicator)
        // findViewById(R.id.viewflowindic);
        // viewFlow.setFlowIndicator(indic);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        showPopup(DemoViewFlowActivity.this);
    }

    // The method that displays the popup.
    private void showPopup(Activity context) {
        int popupWidth = 200;
        int popupHeight = 150;

        // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
        FrameLayout viewGroup = (FrameLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.popup);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.circle_layout, viewGroup);

        // Creating the PopupWindow
        PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
        popup.setContentView(layout);
        popup.setWidth(popupWidth);
        popup.setHeight(popupHeight);
        popup.setFocusable(true);

        // Some offset to align the popup a bit to the right, and a bit down,
        // relative to button's position.
        int OFFSET_X = 30;
        int OFFSET_Y = 30;

        // Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.
        popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 50, 50);

         viewFlow = (ViewFlow) findViewById(R.id.viewflow);
         viewFlow.setAdapter(new DemoDataAdapter(this));
         CircleFlowIndicator indic = (CircleFlowIndicator)
         findViewById(R.id.viewflowindic);
         viewFlow.setFlowIndicator(indic);

        // Getting a reference to Close button, and close the popup when
        // clicked.
        // Button close = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.close);
        // close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        //
        // @Override
        // public void onClick(View v) {
        // popup.dismiss();
        // }
        // });
    }
}
```

here is a part of logcat where error seem to appear:

```
    07-23 23:34:25.960: W/dalvikvm(4048): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
07-23 23:34:25.969: E/AndroidRuntime(4048): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-23 23:34:25.969: E/AndroidRuntime(4048): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.healthcity/com.example.healthcity.activities.DemoViewFlowActivity}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
07-23 23:34:25.969: E/AndroidRuntime(4048):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-23 23:34:25.969: E/AndroidRuntime(4048):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-23 23:34:25.969: E/AndroidRuntime(4048):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-23 23:34:25.969: E/AndroidRuntime(4048):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-23 23:34:25.969: E/AndroidRuntime(4048):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-23 23:34:25.969: E/AndroidRuntime(4048):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-23 23:34:25.969: E/AndroidRuntime(4048):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-23 23:34:25.969: E/AndroidRuntime(4048):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-23 23:34:25.969: E/AndroidRuntime(4048):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-23 23:34:25.969: E/AndroidRuntime(4048):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-23 23:34:25.969: E/AndroidRuntime(4048):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-23 23:34:25.969: E/AndroidRuntime(4048):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-23 23:34:25.969: E/AndroidRuntime(4048): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
07-23 23:34:25.969: E/AndroidRuntime(4048):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:567)
07-23 23:34:25.969: E/AndroidRuntime(4048):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:246)
07-23 23:34:25.969: E/AndroidRuntime(4048):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
07-23 23:34:25.969: E/AndroidRuntime(4048):     at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:993)
07-23 23:34:25.969: E/AndroidRuntime(4048):     at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:847)
07-23 23:34:25.969: E/AndroidRuntime(4048):     at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:811)
07-23 23:34:25.969: E/AndroidRuntime(4048):     at com.example.healthcity.activities.DemoViewFlowActivity.showPopup(DemoViewFlowActivity.java:81)
07-23 23:34:25.969: E/AndroidRuntime(4048):     at com.example.healthcity.activities.DemoViewFlowActivity.onStart(DemoViewFlowActivity.java:54)
07-23 23:34:25.969: E/AndroidRuntime(4048):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1164)
07-23 23:34:25.969: E/AndroidRuntime(4048):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5114)
07-23 23:34:25.969: E/AndroidRuntime(4048):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
```

Comment: do you have the logcat or the stacktrace? does it compile?

Comment: yes it compiles, it works fine if i comment the showPopup call

Comment: Where is line 74 of DemoViewFlowActivity?

Comment: @MonadNewb it is because of this here - `Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?` The pop up is being created in an activity that is not created yet.

Comment: @ObieMD5 , seems so, but its still there after i moved the call to startActivity

Comment: startActivty? You mean OnStart()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code like this:

Replace the call to `showPopup(this)` with:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        showPopup(DemoViewFlowActivity.this);
    }
}, 100L);
```

**Edit 1:**

Usually, a 100 milliseconds delay works wonders in this kind of situation. But, seeing that you are getting the exception even after using a 1 second delay, I tried the following:

I made a simple layout file(say, R.layout.simple_layout) containing only a `LinearLayout`. It does not matter what layout it is. I gave it an `id`(say, @+id/llEmpty). Now, in my onCreate(Bundle), I set the layout using `setContentView(R.layout.simple_layout)`. And, in my `onStart()`, I put the following:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {      
    super.onStart();

    findViewById(R.id.llEmpty).post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // method that creates and displays the popup
            showList();
        }  
    });
}
```

How this will translate to your code:

Your layout file `R.layout.bf_home_screen` probably contains a `RelativeLayout` or a `LinearLayout` as the parent layout. Give the parent layout an `id` using `android:id="@+id/some_id"`. Change your `onStart()` method to:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {      
    super.onStart();

    // Replace "some_id" with the id you use in the layout file
    findViewById(R.id.some_id).post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            showPopup(DemoViewFlowActivity.this);
        }  
    });
}
```

Comment: Forgot `this` after `DemoViewFlowActivity`. Code above should work now.

Comment: @ay89 you should also change `private void showPopup(Activity context)` to `private void showPopup(DemoViewFlowActivity context)`.

Comment: although with 1000ms it works, but it failed a couple of times. is there something we can do about it?

Comment: @ay89 I had another idea. So, I went ahead and created an activity to test it. It works for me. See **Edit 1** above. Hope it works for you.

Comment: thanks vikram. till now it worked perfectly. +1 as only 1 vote is allowed :)

Answer (score 0):

The only strange thing I can see is that you're using the FrameLayout with R.id.popup as the parent when inflating your layout for the PopupWindow.  There's no need for that, and I would pass null.

Answer (score 0):

**onAttachedToWindow** and **onDetachedFromWindow** is your best choice.

And there is no need for postDelayed(Runnable, 100). Because this 100 millis does not guaranties anything

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    Log.d(TAG, "onAttachedToWindow");

    showPopup(DemoViewFlowActivity.this);
}

@Override
public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDetachedFromWindow");

    popup.dismiss();
}
```